# Swift 3 Ranges: Best Practices

Tags: swift, swift3

I downloaded the Xcode 8.0 beta yesterday and consequently Swift 3. The first thing I did was trying to update my project for Swift 3 and I nearly cried. One of the gravest changes is (in my opinion) the new management of Swifts `Range` struct, especially because the automatic conversion to the current Swift syntax does not do anything with the ranges.

`Range` is split into `Range`, `CountableRange`, `ClosedRange` and `CountableClosedRange` which *does* make sense when considering what is now possible when using ranges (though it's mostly fairly unnecessary).

However: I have lots of functions accepting a `Range<Int>` as parameter or returning a `Range<Int>`. The problem is: I called these functions by `0..<5` for example or `0...4` (because it's semantically more expressive sometimes). Of course, I could simply adjust these type of things. But why don't all these range types have a common interface? I'd have to overload every single function for each of these range types and it would perform the exact same operations every time.

Are there any best practices yet for using ranges in Swift 3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple:

A `Closed...Range` is produced by using three dots: `0...10`. This includes lower bound and upper bound. The opposite is a non-closed range, produced by `0..<10` which doesn't include the upper bound.

A `Countable...Range` is a range of a type you can stride through with a signed integer, it is produced by either `0...10` or `0..<10`. These types conform to the `Sequence` protocol.

A few examples:

```
0..<10 // CountableRange
0...Int.max // CountableClosedRange (this was not possible before Swift 3)

"A"..<"A" // Range, empty
"A"..."Z" // ClosedRange, because cannot stride through, only check if a character is in the bounds
```

You should probably make your methods accept a generic `Collection`/`Sequence` depending on what you need:

```
func test<C: Collection where C.Iterator.Element == Int>(s: C) {
    print(s.first)
}
```

Maybe you can show one of your uses for `Range<Int>`

Comment: The last code snippet in your answer was what I was looking for ;) thanks

Answer (score 16):

### Closed Range Operator

The closed range operator `(a...b)` defines a range that runs from `a` to `b`, and includes the values `a` and `b`. The value of `a` must not be greater than `b`.

The closed range operator is useful when iterating over a range in which you want all of the values to be used, such as with a for-in loop:

```
for index in 1...5 {
    print("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")
}
// 1 times 5 is 5
// 2 times 5 is 10
// 3 times 5 is 15
// 4 times 5 is 20
// 5 times 5 is 25
```

### Half-Open Range Operator

The half-open range operator `(a..<b)` defines a range that runs from `a` to `b`, but does not include `b`. It is said to be half-open because it contains its first value, but not its final value. As with the closed range operator, the value of `a` must not be greater than `b`. If the value of `a` is equal to `b`, then the resulting range will be empty.

Half-open ranges are particularly useful when you work with zero-based lists such as arrays, where it is useful to count up to (but not including) the length of the list:

```
let names = ["Anna", "Alex", "Brian", "Jack"]
let count = names.count
for i in 0..<count {
    print("Person \(i + 1) is called \(names[i])")
}
// Person 1 is called Anna
// Person 2 is called Alex
// Person 3 is called Brian
// Person 4 is called Jack
```

Note that the array contains four items, but `0..<count` only counts as far as `3` (the index of the last item in the array), because it is a half-open range.

### Closed Range: `a...b`

```
let myRange = 1...3
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
myArray[myRange] // ["b", "c", "d"]
```

### Half-Open Range: `a..<b`

```
let myRange = 1..<3
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
myArray[myRange] // ["b", "c"]
```

> **Here's a real-world SpriteKit example I had to convert using arc4Random which is in virtually all SpriteKit projects. Random often deals with ranges.**

**Swift 2**

```
Tools.swift

func randomInRange(_ range: Range<Int>) -> Int {
    let count = UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    return  Int(arc4random_uniform(count)) + range.lowerBound
}

GameScene.swift

let gap = CGFloat(randomInRange(StackGapMinWidth...maxGap))
```

**Swift 3**

```
Tools.swift

func randomInRange(range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    let count = UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    return  Int(arc4random_uniform(count)) + range.lowerBound
}

GameScene.swift

let gap = CGFloat(randomInRange(range: StackGapMinWidth...maxGap))
```

So if the `randomInRange()` calculates a random number in the given range, including the upper bound, then it should be defined as `ClosedRange<Bound>`

[Migrating to Swift 3](https://swift.org/migration-guide/)

`Range` and `ClosedRange` can’t be iterated over (they are not collections anymore), since a value that is merely `Comparable` cannot be incremented.
`CountableRange` and `CountableClosedRange` require `Strideable` from their bound and they conform to `Collection` so that you can iterate over them.